# Replace string inside specific folders' file content

Tags: shell, find

I would like to replace string in files that are in specific folders, In other words, I have to avoid replacing string in files which are inside a specific folder.

My Folder structure is,

```
classes
 - Test.ext1
 - Test.ext2
objects
 - Test1.ext1
 - Test1.ext2
staticresources
 - Avoid.ext1
 - Avoid.ext2
```

In the above folder structure, I only need to replace a string in the file contents inside classes and objects folder, not in staticresources folder.

I have tried as below,

```
outputfolder="deploymentFolder"

echo "<---INFO Convert Source to Metadata Format--->"
sfdx force:source:convert --rootdir ../force-app-core/main/default -d ../$outputfolder

echo "<---INFO Replace with empty string in the converted source--->"
find ../$outputfolder ! -path '../$outputfolder/staticresources/*.*' -type f -print0 | \
while IFS= read -r -d '' d;
do
    echo "$d"
    sed -i "s/sp_core__//g" "$d"
done
echo "<---INFO Replace with empty string is Completed--->"
```

Still I can see the files inside staticresources folder processed inside the while loop.

Is there any way we can avoid files which are inside a specific folder to not process?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your find command:

```
find ../$outputfolder ! -path '../$outputfolder/staticresources/*.*' -type f -print0 | \
```

It will not work like this as variable `$outputfolder` following `-path` is surrounded by single quotes and is thus not replaced with its contents.

I'd suggest changing it as follows:

```
find ../$outputfolder ! -path ../$outputfolder/staticresources/'*.*' -type f -print0 | \
```

Also note that `*.*` here only matches files containing a dot. If you want to exclude **all** files, use `*` instead:

```
find ../$outputfolder ! -path ../$outputfolder/staticresources/'*' -type f -print0 | \
```

Last but not least, I'd suggest to use double quotes to make this work for paths containing spaces (not required for your specific example, but generally a good idea):

```
find "../$outputfolder" ! -path "../$outputfolder/staticresources/*" -type f -print0 | \
```